# Does the JSF convertNumber with currency format round or truncate additional decimal places?

Tags: java, jsf

Here is an example:

```
    <h:outputText value="#{myBean.myMoney}">
       <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" />
    </h:outputText>
```

Given that I have $1.006, will this output $1.00 or $1.01?

Doesn't say here:
http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/tlddocs/f/convertNumber.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer=Rounded

Hmmm....does that sound right?  I don't think its a good idea to be rounding up money.  Hopefully no banking apps are going to rely on this one.

Brings to mind this scene from One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest...

> [the inmates are playing cards and betting with cigarettes]
>   Martini: [rips a cigarette in half] I bet a nickel.
>   McMurphy: Dime's the limit, Martini.
>   Martini: I bet a dime.
>   [Puts the two halves onto the table]
>   McMurphy: This is not a dime, Martini. This is a dime.
>   [shows a whole cigarette]
>   McMurphy: If you break it in half, you don't get two nickels, you get shit. Try and smoke it. You understand?
>   Martini: Yes.
>   McMurphy: You don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Currency can be set only to 2 decimal places, setting it to more than 2 decimal places is wrong. If the input is with more than 2 decimal places the output would be truncated to 2 decimal places.

Logically $1.001 would not make any sense as $1 and 1 cent would be $1.01 not $1.001.

Comment: Although, I agree with your response, I was looking for specifically how the convertNumber tag behaved.  After testing it, I know that it is rounding.  The fact that it is getting passed invalid data is another issue altogether.

Comment: -1 It is incorrect, there are many times when fractions of a cent are encountered... one such example is the accrual of interest.  It could also arise from a percentage discount, or any other operation involving division.  The answer is also not helpful, because the question was about the rounding behavior of the tag.